# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() - background Service

Tags: android

My application want to upload data to backend. Upload functionality available 2 places. One is after put invoice, it need to upload to backend without afftect other UI, that means through `Service`another upload functionality will show all table to user if the user click on `Upload` button need to upload, through `AsyncTask`.

Now the problem is, if I call same upload table method then it thow `can't create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare()` this error.

```
06-14 09:53:52.504: W/System.err(2288): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
06-14 09:53:52.514: W/System.err(2288):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:152)
06-14 09:53:52.514: W/System.err(2288):     at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:714)
06-14 09:53:52.514: W/System.err(2288):     at xont.ventura.controller.syn.UploadActivity.<init>(UploadActivity.java:43)
06-14 09:53:52.514: W/System.err(2288):     at xont.ventura.controller.service.UploadService.uploadUsingService(UploadService.java:102)
06-14 09:53:52.514: W/System.err(2288):     at xont.ventura.controller.service.UploadService$ServiceThread.run(UploadService.java:3872)
```

My code is :

```
  @Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Upload Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(! APPURL.equals("")){
        serviceThread = new ServiceThread();
        serviceThread.start();
        if(result.equals("The operation timed out")) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Service is not working  OR Time out to Connect to service !!!!!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPRS/WIFI is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
}

    private class ServiceThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         result = uploadUsingService();
    }   
};


    public String uploadUsingService(){
    uploadTable = getUploadTable();
    String result = "";
    try {
      //  dbAdapter.openDataBase();
        if(uploadTable.size() > 0){
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : uploadTable.entrySet()) {
                String value = entry.getValue();
                if(value.equals("WMInvoiceHeader")){
                    result = new UploadActivity().getInvoiceHeader();
                }else if(value.equals("WMInvoiceLine")){
                    result = new UploadActivity().getInvoiceLine();
                }else if(value.equals("WMInvoiceHeaderDiscount")){
                    result = new UploadActivity().getInvoiceHeaderDiscount();
                }else if(value.equals("WMInvoiceSpecialDiscount")){
                    result = new UploadActivity().getInvoiceSpecialDiscount();
                }else if(value.equals("WMInvoiceCancelHeader")){
                    result = new UploadActivity().getInvoiceCancelHeader();
                }else if(value.equals("WMInvoiceCancelLine")){
                    result = new UploadActivity().getInvoiceCancelLine();
                }else if(value.equals("WMTransactionControl")){
                    result = new UploadActivity().getTransactionControl();
                }else if(value.equals("WMVisitDetail")){
                    result = new UploadActivity().getVisitDetail();
                }
                if(result.equals("The operation timed out")) break;
            }
        }
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Upload Service End", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here the problem is calling `new UploadActivity().functionname` If i write this function inside the same class. it doesn't have any issue. like `getInvoiceCancelLine()` .If i write like this then 2 places have to write upload functionality method. How can i reusable same method 2 place.

Please help me out from this issuse?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you creating handler in any of the UploadActivity().functionname ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI Thread(Event thread) is not thread safe, so you cant do any operation on UI into another thread.
By seeing your code it seems you are doing some UI stuff into method

```
getUploadTable()
```

you can invoke this method outside of another thread, and then pass the result to ServiceThread.

Answer (score 1):

You want run another Thread inside mainActivity, we need one Handler to handle it.

Check out the [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

I think it help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare()

is typically caused when you try to do stuff to UI-elements on a non-UI-thread.

You have shown only snippet of code.so can not certainly comment exactly where you have done mistake.But make sure your are not trying to access or modify UI elements inside ServiceThread.

If you can show more code to us we can help you.